# Using fermats last theorem in a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question:

> If $x,y,z,n$ are natural numbers, $x,y,z,n>1$, with $x^n +y^n=z^n$ then show that $x,y,z$ are all greater than $n$

Here to prove this i would like to use Fermat's last theorem, to show that $n=2$ and then use the property of Pythagorean triplets to show that $x,y,z$ are greater than $n$.Can this method be used in a proof?

Comment: Sounds fine. By property of pythagorean triple, I take you mean the 'smallest' triplet is 3,4,5 I take?

Comment: This is a rather heavy weapon. It's correct (according to todays state of knoowledge) but I would try to check whether a more elementary reasoning allows to cover the case $n\ge 3$

Comment: Further to @Thomas point, an advanced result like Fermat's last theorem may well already have used the result you are proving, perhaps via a chain of other earlier results, so you may actually have a circular argument.

Comment: @JackYoon Yeah,that what i mean.

Comment: yes all of x,y,z,n are greater than 1

Comment: @Joffan there is no problem in using a result to prove a result that was used to prove the original result unless one of them is false. In some sense it's circular, but it doesn't matter provided the results are true.. Otherwise you'd have to check the proof of every single result in fear that what you're trying to deduce was used in the proof.

Comment: @MattSamuel OK - maybe it's just aesthetics then, or my sense of what it means to prove something.

Comment: Notice that as the bases $x,y,z$ are positive, and may be taken to be relatively prime without loss of generality (including a common factor would increase $x,y,z$ without changing $n$), you can assume $x \lt y \lt z$ and focus efforts on showing $x \gt n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all means examine Pythagorean triplets for n=2, but it isn't really necessary.

For $n\geq 2$ and taking $x \leq y<z$, note that
$\begin{align}
x^n = z^n-y^n &= (z-y)\overbrace{(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}y+\ldots + zy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})}^{n \text{ terms}} \\
 &>ny^{n-1} \geq nx^{n-1}\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow x^n > nx^{n-1}\Rightarrow x>n$ as required.

Comment: This is the same proof given in my book. The factorization that you have done,is show in the solution though its the first time i'm seeing  a factorization technique like this .

Comment: Once you know that $(z-y)$ is a viable factor of $(z^n-y^n)$ - which it always is - you can divide out to find the remaining factor if necessary.